# Android - Update list as database updates

Tags: java, android, sqlite, cursor, simplecursoradapter

I'm looking for a method to update my ListView as my database is updating.

For instance when the app first loads, I asynchronously call my database and perform an insert of all the data (this takes up to 30seconds for all the API calls and inserts to run and is only performed on the first creation of the app). During which time I would like to be able to have the user navigate the app and once they get to a page that requires database information, I want the page to load with the current available data, and continue to update as more information is placed in the database.

At the same time, if a user is on a given page and the database gets updated in the background with additional information for that list, I would like the list to updated.

The async calls to the database are made in a separate class.

Thanks,
Dman

Comment: On the onPostExecute method of the asyncTask you can call : listAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

Comment: if you're using ContentProviders, check out ContentObservers.

Comment: @AlexisCartier Not sure if that is what I'm looking for. On the first load of the app the data is retrieved (but this isn't the page that uses the data hence the list in not in existance). The first page is a menu. From here the user can then navigate to the pages in which the lists will be used. Once they navigate to one of these screens I perform an async grab of the data, but while the async retrieval is occurring, the data may not even exist in the DB yet (or only partially exist) and hence I need to continuously grab data from the DB until all of it is retrieved.

Comment: @TomislavNovoselec I am using a SimpleCursorAdapter which I have overridden and customized to my list needs. Not sure if that's the same as what you are describing.

Comment: it's similar. When you are creating a new instance of your extended SimpleCursorAdapter, you can pass a flag named FLAG_REGISTER_CONTENT_OBSERVER. it will fire onContentChanged listener and then you can refresh your views. 

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CursorAdapter.html#FLAG_REGISTER_CONTENT_OBSERVER

Comment: @TomislavNovoselec Can you please elaborate on when it will fire the onContentChanged event? I guess another question related to this I have is how do I register additional data to the cursor? ie I call my AsyncLoadData class it gets 5 records. Then a few seconds later 5 more are added which were not loaded during the asyncLoadData call. Does a cursor stay open (until closed) and keep querying after a set amount of time? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ContentProvider was able to do the trick. Thanks a lot.